# Handling two different Retrofit responses for success and error in Kotlin

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

I'm building an android app in Kotlin, and the response comes in two different structures for success and error. My question is, can I combine those two responses together and create a data class, or should I create a sealed class for that?
Success response:

```
{
    "access_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

Error response:

```
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body"
            ],
            "msg": "Invalid credentials",
            "type": "invalid-credentials"
        }
    ]
}
```

So can I write it all like this in a single data class or use a sealed class?

```
data class Auth (
   val access_token: String,
   val token_type: String,
   val details: Details
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes try combining all the data into a single data class. Just make all the variables optional.

```
data class Auth (
   val access_token: String?,
   val token_type: String?,
   val detail: List<Detail>?
)
```

Edit: On how to access the nested data. Pretty Simple.

```
data class Detail ( 
  val loc: List<String>,
  val msg: String,
  val type: String
)
```

Then when an error occurs you access the data with something like `val msg = auth.detail?.msg`

Comment: So you think it won't be the need of a sealed class with to data classes depending on success and error, would it work just the same?

Comment: That's unnecessary. Using sealed classes would be overengineering for the example that you gave.

Comment: But how am I supposed to access for the observe method msg or loc or type that are part of the Details class?

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I tried that method for accessing msg, loc or type and I couldn't access it I don't know why

Comment: I just looked at the model again try `val detail: List<Detail>? `

Comment: No the problem that I mentioned was on the val msg = auth.detail?.msg this didn't work, it wasn't recognized